# Perl regular expression split help needed

Tags: regex, perl, split

I'm trying to split records like these

```
123.45.67.89/24 - String - Other string details (/25-/30)
```

into 3 variables containing `"123.45.67.89","24"` and `"String - Other string details (/25-/30)"`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use Data::Dumper;

$file = "Network_Usage.clean";

open (Network_Usage,$file);

while (<Network_Usage>) {
        chomp;
        my $row = $_;
        my @array = $row =~ /((([0-9]{1,3})\.{0,1}){4})\/([0-9]{1,2}) - (.*)/;
        print Dumper ( @array);
        exit;
}

close (Network_Usage);
```

But I'm getting this result :

```
root@host:~/# ./split.pl 
$VAR1 = '123.45.67.89'; 
$VAR2 = '89'; 
$VAR3 = '89'; 
$VAR4 = '24'; 
$VAR5 = '';
```

Event if it is doing the job for me ( I can use `$VAR1,4,5`). I would like to know what am I doing wrong to receive the results in `$VAR2/3`.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution I can find is to limit the result, so only let the `split()` to work twice:

```
my @arr = split /[\/\s-]+/, $s, 3
```

It yields:

```
0  '123.45.67.89'
1  24
2  'String - Other string details (/25-/30)'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep this from capturing the `89` twice by using non-capturing groups.  Just add a `?:` to the beginning of the group that you do not want to capture.  Try changing your regex to the following:

```
/((?:(?:[0-9]{1,3})\.{0,1}){4})\/([0-9]{1,2}) - (.*)/
   ^  ^
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex would work:

```
([0-9]{1,3}[\.]?[0-9]{1,3}[\.]?[0-9]{1,3}[\.]?[0-9]{1,3}[\.]?)\/([\d]+) - (.*)
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/sC2uN3

Matches:

```
MATCH 1
1.  `123.45.67.89`
2.  `24`
3.  `String - Other string details (/25-/30)`
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can do use this in your regex matching:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $t="123.45.67.89/24 - String - Other string details (/25-/30)";

if ($t =~ /(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\/(\d+)\s+(.*)/){
    print "$1\n"; #Prints "123.45.67.89"
    print "$2\n"; #Prints "24"
    print "$3\n"; #Prints "- String - Other string details (/25-/30)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `-` and `/` are always the record separators, you could also use the [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) function:

```
my $filename = "Network_Usage.clean";
open (my $network_file, '<', $file);

while (my $row = <$network_file>) {
        chomp;
        my @array = split /[\/\s-]/, $row; 
        print Dumper @array;
}

close($network_file);
```

A couple points on style:

1. it is typical to assign the `$row` *inside* of the while condition
2. BAREWORD filehandles are usually discouraged

Comment: I think that the slash is special inside a character class too. It will give a syntax error unless you escape it.

Comment: You'll get extra unwanted splits in the string if it contains a hyphen or a slash though, as in the example (contains two hyphens and two slashes).

Comment: @Birei - No, just use a different regex delimiter than "/".. `split m![/\s-]!, $row;`